# Enviar e receber SMS via PC

Tags: android, ios, mobile, sms

Estou fazendo um software interno que precisa de alguns dados que são recebidos via SMS, o cliente envia o SMS com algumas informações e atualmente eu preciso fazer manualmente o reenvido das SMS. Eu pretendo automatizar o processo pra se tornar mais rápido, prático e menos suscetível a falhas humanas.

Alguém conhece algum componente que utiliza um chip GSM que eu consiga ler todas as SMS que este chip recebe e envie SMS com as respostas?

Pensei em talvez comprar um Arduino e uma placa GSM pra fazer tal operação, mas creio que já deve existir algo bem mais prático.

Ressalto que não importa a linguagem de programação que necessite saber para tal operação, se for preciso aprender uma nova não vejo problemas.

Comment: Acho que não fui bem claro, vou explicar o processo parcialmente:
Meus funcionários me manda regularmente informações sobre o status atual do serviço que eles estão executando para que eu informe ao meu sistema o andamento da situação, e é uma situação bem simples. Ele avisa: Serviço: [ID], St: Aguardando liberação do gate.

Logo eu atualizo no sistema (que é um site) sobre a liberação do gate, meu cliente acompanha passo a passo sobre o trabalho.

Comment: Hoje esse processo é muito manual e a chance de ocorrer um esquecimento é grande, pois as vezes chegam diversas SMS e hora ou outra é esquecido de lançar, o que ocasiona uma não conformidade.
É isso o que eu quero evitar, ao receber a SMS o sistema irá guardar e perguntar para o usuário se pode publicar o status (ou corrigir possíveis erros de ortografia).
Compreende?

Comment: Até onde eu sei @Bacco, não existe regra da operadora contra automatização, mas sim um limite máximo de envio mensal e diário. Não há problemas em se usar modems GPRS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A essência da comunicação por modems GSM em geral é a mesma dos modems seriais.

Os SMSs são enviados e recebidos por comandos AT, que são meras strings escritas e lidas da respectiva porta serial (geralmente virtual, por USB).

### Exemplo de envio:

- Os itens em negrito sua aplicação envia;
- em itálico está a resposta do modem;
- `\r` é o "enter"

> **AT+CMGF=1** `\r`
>   *OK*
>   **AT+CMGS="+99999999999"** `\r`
>   *>* **Esta e a mensagem** `\r`
>   *OK*

Na primeira linha estamos entrando em modo texto, aí aguardamos o `OK` do modem para iniciar um SMS para o número entre aspas. Ao entrar com o número, o modem retorna `>`, o que significa que está aguardando a mensagem. Ao enviar a mensagem e mais uma quebra de linha, o modem continua aguardando mais dados. Para encerrar, basta enviar um <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (equivale ao `chr(26)` ASCII).

### Exemplo de recebimento:

> **AT+CMGL="ALL"** `\r`
>   *+CMGL: 123,"REC READ","+123456789"*
>   *Eu sou a mensagem!*

Esta é uma explicação para dar uma noção inicial do processo. Após decidir qual vai ser a linguagem utilizada, é possível entrar em mais detalhes de como implementar na prática.

Comment: isso não seria uma possível solução para o [meu problema](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12413/enviar-sms-de-um-dispositivo-movel-via-html5-javascript)?

Comment: @JorgeB. HTML e JS normalmente não tem acesso a esse tipo de comunicação com dispositivos. No seu caso provavelmente só código nativo resolve.