# Enviar sms de um dispositivo móvel via HTML5/javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, cross-platform, mobile

Estou a criar uma aplicação WEB para dispositivo móvel que será descarregada numa das store's, com um mini WEB server integrado e que funcione em qualquer sistema operativo(iOS, android, windows8, etc).

Para que a aplicação seja o mais independente possível do sistema operativo queria apenas usar `HTML5` e `JavaScript`.

A aplicação permite a um utilizador fazer uma série de pedidos clicando apenas em botões. 
Exemplo: [Ver contactos]

Preciso que ao clicar em [Ver contactos] seja enviada uma `sms` de forma automática para outro dispositivo móvel com uma aplicação `android` que recebe o pedido, trata e envia a resposta via sms. A resposta também tem de ser lida pela minha aplicação WEB. Isto para que a aplicação funcione sem rede móvel/Wifi.

Já estive a pesquisar e só encontro formas de fazer com que se abra a aplicação de envio de sms do meu dispositivo móvel.

Existe alguma forma de fazer este envio de forma automática?

E se não existir poderá ser feito doutra forma? Tipo usar/criar um plugin para usar no JavaScript que me faça isso?

[EDIT]
Vi [isto](http://www.w3.org/2012/sysapps/messaging/#h2_introduction) ontem e andei já a pesquisar sobre o assunto, mas parece que o trabalho foi [descontinuado](http://www.w3.org/TR/messaging-api/), infelizmente. Não sei sequer se seria uma hipótese.

Comment: Você vai precisar de uma linguagem que trabalhe do lado do servidor, C#, Java, PHP e outras. Já que HTML5 e java script é apenas uma linguagem front-end.

Comment: Não tem mesmo hipótese de fazer isso só com HTML5 e javascript?

Comment: até existe sim a possibilidade do html+javascript fazer isso, porém quando existe algo no servidor para isso, ex: existe componentes onde o javascript poderia ler e postar, porém claro..normalmente esse back-end é desenvolvido pela mesma pessoa do front-end..

Comment: Adicionei a tag Android creio que a comunidade de programadores Android possam ajudar.

Comment: Você chegou a considerar a possibilidade de usar um serviço Web de envio de SMS como o [Zeep Mobile](http://www.zeepmobile.com/default/) (tem versão gratuita com a inclusão de propaganda) ou o [Zenvia](http://www.zenvia.com.br/connect-sms-corporativo/geral/)?

Comment: Não posso, tem de ser enviada pelo próprio dispositivo móvel, é um dos requisitos para poder funcionar offline.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Atualmente não tem como enviar SMS apenas com HTML sem escrever código nativo**, o mais próximo que você vai conseguir é abrir o aplicativo de envio de mensagens com os campos preenchidos, para fazer isso utilize.

```
<a href="sms:99999999?body=Oi">Clique para enviar oi</a>
```

A sintaxe é:

```
sms[to]://[<destination number>][?parameters].
```

O parâmetro número do telefone é opcional.

Se você realmente quer enviar isso sem abrir o sender do Android os modos são:

1. Com javascript você chamar alguma função em um servidor web (asp.net, php, etc) que envie o SMS p/ você.
2. Criar um código nativo Android que intercepte a ação do HTML e envie.

Fontes:

http://paulohdsousa.blogspot.com.br/2014/04/android-enviar-sms-utilizando-html.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869297/html5-mobile-app-vs-email-sms

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721437/how-to-initiate-send-sms-from-a-html5-webpage-using-devices-native-functions

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2166-how-to-send-a-text-message-from-your-mobile-website/

Comment: E se não existir poderá ser feito doutra forma? Tipo usar/criar um plugin para usar no JavaScript que me faça isso? E que seja compatível com os vários sistemas operativos?

Comment: O único modo é pelo javascript você chamar alguma função em um servidor web (asp.net, php, etc) que faça isso. ou então algum código nativo Android.

Comment: Pois isso eu sei, mas assim não dá para o que eu preciso.

Comment: @JorgeB. não entendo o porquê. Se você criar uma API de envio de SMS em uma linguagem server side, pode chamar isso tranquilamente com JS puro. Com certeza há um serviço que possibilite isso. Se você quer enviar SMS nativamente do aparelho, muito provavelmente há APIs pra isso também, se for algo considerado aceitável pelo desenvolvedor do OS.

Comment: Acho que o principal motivo é a segurança. Não há a possibilidade de você "invadir" o Android para "obrigar" o sistema a enviar uma mensagem de SMS. Se isso fosse possível iria se tornar um caos com diversas páginas na web realizando este procedimento (para o mal, é claro!).

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira se eu fizer isso é garantido que funcione na maioria dos OS e sem internet ligada?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, você quer usar o envio de SMS do próprio aparelho. Não sei se dá pra fazer isso com JS. Se der, é uma API do próprio desenvolvedor do OS.

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira sim é isso mesmo. Por isso é que está complicado, ainda por cima tem de ser compatível com todos os OS.

Comment: conseguiu fazer ?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível fazer utilizando somente javascript. Porém, utilizando Cordova é possível desenvolver aplicativos móveis utilizando HTML, CSS e Javascript. Ele possui diversos plug-ins, dentre eles um para enviar e receber SMS. Site do cordova: https://cordova.apache.org/. Plug-in de SMS: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/

Comment: Mas esses plugins não são em código java e objetive-c?

Comment: Eles são utilizados através de linguagem javasdript

Comment: Eu fui ver o plug-in, e ele é feito em Android para usar depois com Javascript. Não serve para mim, mas obrigado na mesma.