# Existe algum serviço back-end que responda a mensagens SMS?

Tags: sms, request, back-end

Estou fazendo uma pesquisa sobre operações que envolvam comunicação com back-end que utilizam mensagens de SMS para interagir com usuários.

Não consegui encontrar algo relevante no Google, que explique de forma clara sobre como este serviço funciona. Alguém saberia dizer por onde começar de forma clara?

A idéia seria o seguinte:

- User envia uma mensagem de texto para um numero X
- O servidor receberia a mensagem e iria "ler" o conteúdo da string
- Após interpretar a strings iria realizar uma ação e responder a mensagem para o usuário

  Caso não tenha sido claro, poderei complementar a pergunta conforme o necessário.

Comment: Andei pesquisando, e das duas uma: ou é empresa "chipeira", que é bom evitar (e tem umas famosas no Brasil), ou é caro demais em vista de outros países. Já considerou a possibilidade de instalar um modem GSM no seu servidor e deixar ele ter numero próprio? Aí basta mandar comandos AT para o modem e ler direto dele. De qq forma, espero que saia uma resposta boa aqui. De quebra, se alguém vier fazer propaganda de "chipeira" aqui, dá pra gente descontrair nos comentários. (chipeiras são aquelas empresas "caseiras" que, entre outras coisas vc identifica por usarem números convencionais de celular)

Comment: kkk nao nao a parada é seria, estou fazendo um estudo de como funciona esse sistema. Tem fins educacionais sérios.

Comment: Vamos ver se alguém conhece alguma empresa com uma API boa pra isso, mas se não aparecer nada e vc quiser se aventurar, tem algumas coisas no site sobre SMS: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12132/70 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sms+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @Bacco já fez o comentário/resposta pertinente. Caso você possua conhecimentos em desenvolvimento mobile, pode utilizar um equipamento Android para interceptar mensagens SMS e então enviar seu conteúdo para um webservice, por exemplo. Neste caso o celular se tornou um *Broker*, na linguagem de integração. Só não fique sem créditos. ;)

Comment: A ideia do modem é excelente. É normal receber SMS de empresas grandes com números convencionais. O único problema é que você precisa de acesso físico ao servidor... Inclusive, já vi uns modens da Daruma (nacional) com API para diversas linguagens back-end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme comentário feito por @Bacco:

> Vamos ver se alguém conhece alguma empresa com uma API boa pra isso,
>   mas se não aparecer nada e vc quiser se aventurar, tem algumas coisas
>   no site sobre SMS: pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12132/70 e
>   pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sms+is%3Aquestion

Aceito como resposta válida!

Comment: Melhor deixarmos mais um pouco pra ver o que acontece. Pode ser que saia alguma resposta. Mas se alguma outra já existente atender sua necessidade, nos indique. Agradeço a indicação do comentário, mas creio que esteja melhor como comentário apenas, do que resposta.

Comment: Bom, pelo tempo que ficou ninguém mais respondeu. Mas caso alguém queria comentar, sugestões são sempre bem vindas!

Comment: Já pesquisei um bocado sobre isso, a empresa que já vi mais recomendações é a twilio.com , entra lá q os caras são sérios. Vc vai achar facilmente outras opções se pesquisar por twilio no google. Esperto ter ajudado.